# Fixed header and fixed right scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the script header fixed and fixed right scrollbar that I would like to use, just like Facebook. But I want the right side div to not be fixed. I'm fixed position. div shifting to the left this time.

I want it to be fixed to the right of the black `div.Header`, which has `height: 40px;`

This is Demo in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3p2U/)

This is my **HTML CODE**:

```
<div class="globalHeader"><div class="globalHader-in"></div></div>
<div class="global_container"><div class="container">
    <div class="ksmsl"></div>
    <div class="ksmort"></div>
    <div class="ksmsg"></div>


</div></div>
```

and also **CSS code** :

```
body{
   margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
.globalHeader {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#2a3542;
    z-index:99999;
    }
.globalheader-in {
    width:981px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    }
.global_container{
    clear:both;
    width:981px;
    height: 100000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    }
.container{
    float:left;
    width:981px;
    height:auto;

    }
.ksmsl{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;

    }
.ksmsg{
    float:right;
    width:199px;
    height:1000px;

    background-color:#000;
    }
.ksmort{
    float:left;
    width:560px;
    height:auto;
    border-left:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    border-right:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    }
```

Comment: I can go ahead and tell you that it's bad practice to make the `.global_container` class `height: 100000px;`, Instead you should let the content determine the height; otherwise you will have to preload all of that height (which takes a while), and it will look bad when you don't have enough content to fill it out. Just set `* {height: 100%;}` or something.

Comment: @TylerH I know this, this is only example

Comment: If you know it and you aren't going to use it, why put it in your example?

Comment: @TylerH because i want to learn how can i fixed scrollbar.!!

Comment: You will still have the scrollbar in JSFiddle if you set body height equal to 100% and remove the fixed height of 100000px from the global_container class.

Comment: @TylerH ok can you give me a little example in jsfiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/g3p2U/2/ You will still have the scrollbar because you have the right sidebar set to a height of `1000px`, so as long as the viewport is less than 1000px high, you will scroll.

Comment: @TylerH but I just want the rightmost black color div fixed. Your example is all .global_container

Comment: @TylerH http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/g3p2U/7/ i updated link. problem is now div going to left :(

Answer (score 1):

Fix your sidebar and instead of floating it right, you say right: 0; [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3p2U/4/)

```
.ksmsg{
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width:199px;
    height:1000px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#000;
    }
```

As for keeping the fixed sidebar within the container, you cannot contain a fixed div. Please refer to: [Fixed position div not staying contained in wrapping div, overlays entire screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146971/fixed-position-div-not-staying-contained-in-wrapping-div-overlays-entire-screen)

Comment: thanks your reply but my container width only 981px if i do your code in my css .ksmsg  not be where it should be

Comment: i am updated my example can you check it . I want only black div fixed. This tutorial i used javascript but .ksmsg div normaly right side so when i say position:absolute it will go left side. fixed is ok but position is not ok. http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/g3p2U/6/

Comment: You cannot contain a fixed div. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146971/fixed-position-div-not-staying-contained-in-wrapping-div-overlays-entire-screen